# grok when to use quotes in shell scripting

Tags: linux, bash, shell, scripting

When BASH scripting, I am often confused when to put variables in quotes or just have them called without quotes.

```
"$i" vs. $i 
echo hello vs echo "hello"
-eq vs == 
$((i%2))
```

Could someone point me to a resource that explains this well or give me some basic tips? Thanks.

Comment: http://mywiki.wooledge.org/Quotes, http://mywiki.wooledge.org/Arguments and http://wiki.bash-hackers.org/syntax/words are good places to start.

Comment: In general -- you should quote **every** expansion (like `$i`) unless you **explicitly want** word-splitting and glob expansion to occur on its contents, or are **entirely certain** that its contents cannot expand to anything but a single word (this will frequently be the case for numeric evaluations, though even then bugs &c. can make a variable you expected to have a number expand to 0 words rather than 1, making quoting help your script fail closer to underlying errors). Similarly, any string containing glob characters, whitespace, or other syntactically-significant content.

Comment: Beyond that -- this actually isn't one question, but... three? Four? `-eq` vs `=` (vs `==`) is very much a separate concern (and also depends on whether you're using `test`/`[`, `[[`, `((`, etc). As such, it's a bit broad as presently asked.

Comment: ...mind you, if you don't know the value of `IFS`, it's possible for even string guaranteed to be composed of numbers to expand to more than one word; if `IFS=2`, and `x=123`, then `$x` unquoted will expand to `'1' '3'`. If you want absolute certainty? Quote.

Comment: (`==` is a bash extension -- the POSIX sh syntax for string equality comparisons in `test` or `[` is only a single `=`; for the sake of being in habits that will still work with other shells barring cases where you want to break compatibility for a good reason, I suggest using only a single `=` rather than making `==` a habit).

Answer (score 0):

Here's the basic tip: **always** double-quote your variable usages in Bash, unless you know for sure you need to not quote them.  Quoting them is safer, as it prevents word splitting; you will know during development when you need word splitting and therefore should not quote a variable.